# need help for my php coding

Tags: php, html, mysql

I was trying to do a school project and the result only shows me 1 data from my MySQL table. Here is the code:

```
<?php
include("connect.php");
$view_users_query= "select * from data_cuti"; 
$run= mysql_query($view_users_query);
while($row= mysql_fetch_array($run)){               
    $name=$row['Name'];  
    $startdate=$row['startdate'];
    $finaldate=$row['finaldate'];  
    $within=$row['within'];
    $reason=$row['reason'];
    $remaining=$row['remaining'];
    $status=$row['status'];
    $id=$row['id'];     
}
?>  
    <tr>            
        <td><?php echo $name;  ?></td>
        <td><?php echo $startdate;  ?></td>
        <td><?php echo $finaldate;  ?></td>   
        <td><?php echo $within;  ?></td>
        <td><?php echo $reason;  ?></td> 
        <td><?php echo $remaining; ?></td>
        <td><?php echo $status;  ?></td>
    </tr>                                         
</table>
```

Can anyone help tell me what did I am missing?

Comment: close the while loop after `</tr>`. eg `</tr><?php } ?></table>`

Comment: Your `while` skims over all the result `$row`s. What's left to the output block *afterwards* is just the state of the last `$row`.

Comment: Don't know php, but shouldn't you iterate over the echo's instead of calling each entry only once ? Also they are downvoting your question because it was poorly formatted, and also because I think homework questions aren't well accepted.

Comment: soory was i'm new to this

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As the other commenters have said, you need to include the output block **within** the while loop, else you will only get the output from the last row.

Try this:

```
<table>
<?php
include("connect.php");
$view_users_query= "select * from data_cuti"; 
$run= mysql_query($view_users_query);
while($row= mysql_fetch_array($run)){               
    $name=$row['Name'];  
    $startdate=$row['startdate'];
    $finaldate=$row['finaldate'];  
    $within=$row['within'];
    $reason=$row['reason'];
    $remaining=$row['remaining'];
    $status=$row['status'];
    $id=$row['id'];     
    ?>  
    <tr>            
        <td><?php echo $name;  ?></td>
        <td><?php echo $startdate;  ?></td>
        <td><?php echo $finaldate;  ?></td>   
        <td><?php echo $within;  ?></td>
        <td><?php echo $reason;  ?></td> 
        <td><?php echo $remaining; ?></td>
        <td><?php echo $status;  ?></td>
    </tr>
<?php } ?>                                       
</table>
```

Really all the intermediate variables you're using are redundant, so this is equivalent and much shorter:

```
<table>
<?php
include("connect.php");
$view_users_query= "select * from data_cuti"; 
$run= mysql_query($view_users_query);
while($row= mysql_fetch_array($run)){                   
    ?>  
    <tr>            
        <td><?php echo $row['Name'];  ?></td>
        <td><?php echo $row['startdate'];  ?></td>
        <td><?php echo $row['finaldate'];  ?></td>   
        <td><?php echo $row['within'];  ?></td>
        <td><?php echo $row['reason'];  ?></td> 
        <td><?php echo $row['remaining']; ?></td>
        <td><?php echo $row['status'];  ?></td>
    </tr>
<?php } ?>                                       
</table>
```

Or more concise still, without the messy switching between html and php modes:

```
<?php
include("connect.php");
$view_users_query= "select * from data_cuti"; 
$run= mysql_query($view_users_query);
echo "<table>";
while($row= mysql_fetch_array($run)){                    
    echo "<tr>";
    echo "<td>$row['Name']</td>";
    echo "<td>$row['startdate']</td>";
    echo "<td>$row['finaldate']</td> ";  
    echo "<td>$row['within']</td>";
    echo "<td>$row['reason']</td>";
    echo "<td>$row['remaining']</td>";
    echo "<td>$row['status']</td>";
    echo "</tr>";
}                                     
echo "</table>";
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want headers too, you can do as below:

```
<?php include("connect.php");?>
<table>
<tr>
<th>Name</th>
<th>Start Date</th>
<th>Final Date</th>
<th>Within</th>
<th>Reason</th>
<th>Remaining</th>
<th>Status</th>
</tr>
<?php
$view_users_query= "select * from data_cuti"; 
$run= mysql_query($view_users_query) or die(mysql_error());
?>
<?php 
while($row= mysql_fetch_array($run)){                   
?>  
<tr>            
    <td><?php echo $row['Name'];  ?></td>
    <td><?php echo $row['startdate'];  ?></td>
    <td><?php echo $row['finaldate'];  ?></td>   
    <td><?php echo $row['within'];  ?></td>
    <td><?php echo $row['reason'];  ?></td> 
    <td><?php echo $row['remaining']; ?></td>
    <td><?php echo $row['status'];  ?></td>
  </tr>
<?php } ?>                                       
</table>
```